# Transforming an XSD template to an XML instance in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have an XSD file(s), and I need to generate a valid sample XML from that XSD file.
For example, given the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Recipient" type="xs:string" default="John Doe" />
        <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="dateborn" type="xs:date"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Generate the following XML:

```
<xml>
    <Address>
        <Recipient>John Doe</Recipient>
        <Street></Street>
        <age>43</age>
        <dateborn>1970-03-27</dateborn>
    </Address>
</xml>
```

I've searched for a solution in PHP that is capable of performing this, but only to come across two possible solutions but with no success.

1. Using SDO_DAS_XML . However, this depends on tha availability of php_sdo.dll, to which there doesn't seem be a version that actually works on Windows.
2. Second try was to look at github.com/moyarada/XSD-to-PHP or 
   forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/xml-schema-binding-to-php-code-jaxb-equivalent-199799.html
   However, these are targeted at parsing XSD and transforming to PHP classes and don't seem to be generic enoguh to transform any XSD to a simple clean XML (like above).

Any ideas or solutions are much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'll clarify, that I need the simplest form of this XSD generated as an empty XML according to the XSD rules (including default/fixed values, attributes, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the only reasonable way to perform this task is to treat your XSD as any XML, use DOMDocument to parse it and build your specialized XML instances from it.

- This method assumes that your XSD will always have the same structure, only different names to fields, and that you're interested in a very simple form of XML instance, meaning the nodes and nothing more.
- The benefit of that method is in flexibility, simply edit the foreach loop to modify your special structure.

```php
//Build the template from the schema:
$schema = new DOMDocument();
$schema->loadXML($schemaXSDFile); //that is a String holding your XSD file contents
$fieldsList = $schema->getElementsByTagName('element'); //get all elements 
$metadataTemplate = '';
foreach ($fieldsList as $element) {
    //add any special if statements here and modify the below to include any attributes needed
    $key = $element->getAttribute('name');
    $metadataTemplate .= '<' . $key . '>' . '</' . $key . '>';
}

//Manipulate the template adding your fields values:
$metadataXml = simplexml_load_string($metadataTemplate);
$metadataXml->fieldName = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your quest to find a solution because I needed one myself.

For everyone on the quest to find a solution :

Found [XSD2PHP Original](https://github.com/davidgillen/XSD2PHP) and forked it to fit my needs better [Updated Version](https://github.com/florian25686/XSD2PHP) .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything in PHP but I came across this - http://sourceforge.net/projects/camprocessor/

Its in JAVA but as its open-source, you may try finding exact java class being used for XML sample generation from given XSD. After that same class's logic may be implemented in PHP.

May sound impractical, but this is closed I could get! :|